# How many 5-year extensions are allowed on a PPF account?

Tags: investing, india

Once your PPF account completes 15 years, I understand it gets extended for 5-year terms. Is there a limit on the number of such extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation on the number of 5-year term extension on PPF